# Resuming a Multithreaded program that parses a file after crashing

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a single thread program, that parses the contents of a file and gives me an output. For the single threaded program, I'm creating a dump file and updating it regularly for each line read so that, even if the system crashes the program will resume from the last execution point. Now, I want to implement this as a multi threaded program, but I'm confused as to what I'll do in the case of crash. Since multiple threads will be running in parallel how can I resume from the last execution point. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html?is-external=true

Comment: How are you dividing the file to multiple threads ? Please provide an example of this

Comment: @AxelH : I'm mapping a region of the file into memory using the map function in FileChannel class. Then the threads are reading from that block of memory

Comment: So if this is only the reading thread that crash, the memory is still there, you just need to be able to keep track of reading position

Comment: i think i am missing something, why don't you use try/catch? what is the point of crashing?

Comment: @AxelH I'm talking about whole system crash, not the processing thread.

Comment: My bad, didn't get that part. Well, you will need to be able to remap the file indenticaly (same block size) for each thread. And you should be able to skip the line already processed if you keep track of this for each thread. But with an example, hard to say if you will be able to do anything

Answer (score 0):

use mulitthread to read a file is not a good idea. if yours processing logic is time costing, you can use one thread to read content from a file and then forward it to a pool of processing threading.

crash recovery is a long period, Oracle need several hours to recovery , so trying to use mulitthread  to speed up recovery procedure is ridiculous

Comment: I would use the same logic, since you will read the file on one thread (you are still limited in IO speed depending on the HDD so multithread is not necessary I think), you can track the number of line already processed, so you can get back on correct position after a crash, might need to validated some line from there (if one thread didn't had the time to notify the main thread that a line was processed.